# What is the meaning of "abstract out" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

> So, in principle, with a brain connectivity map we would have a vast trove of objective data about the
>   brain, and with our own introspection, we have a vast trove of subjective data about consciousness. One
>   might think it would then be possible to **abstract out** the relevant kinds of principles that connect the
>   objective to the subjective. I don’t think this would mean that we would bridge the mind/brain gap, but we
>   would have boiled down this conundrum to the simplest possible principles.
>
> source: The enigma of human consciousness.New York Academy of Sciences.

What is the meaning of "abstract out" in this context?

Comment: distill from, extract only the parts necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you (are able to) only take the relevant parts. "Abstract" here is a verb that means "to remove or extract".

From Collins,

> If you abstract something from a place, you take it from there.
>
> [formal]
>
> - ...a licence to abstract water from the River Axe.
> - The author has abstracted poems from earlier books.